# Any open source/free software that allows me to superimpose a PNG file on video?

Tags: video-editing

I want to insert pictures and words into a video, and the graphic file is in PNG format.

Answer (score 0):

One of [Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/)'s video filters will allow you to do this.

Comment: that sounds good, do you have a link to the video filter?

Comment: It's one of the filters that come with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Blender. If you're good with 3D texturing and shading, and you read up on the tutorials, you might be able to layer that PNG image over the video, although you might lose the video's sound.